How to Properly Bind the Button in Xamarin Forms
Can someone explain to me why my content is not showing when I add the Button with Binding, but if I don't add the Binding, it will show the content of my page?
HomePage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventWebApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="EventWebApp.Views.HomePage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:HomeViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="List of Events" FontSize="32" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding userId}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="50" Padding="20, 10, 20, 0" BackgroundColor="#C05858">
                            <Image Source="{Binding event_image}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_name}" FontSize="24" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_description}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_date}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_time}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_location}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding event_organizer}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Grid Padding="20,10,20,20" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Join" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.JoinEvent, Source={x:Reference Events}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

HomeViewModel.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EventWebApp.Models;
using EventWebApp.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EventWebApp.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : EventsInterface
    {
        public int UserId { get; private set; }
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Home";
            JoinEvent = new Command<Event>(OnJoin);
            _ = LoadEventsAsync();
        }

        public void SetUserId(int userId)
        {
            UserId = userId;
            LoadEventsForUser(userId);
        }

        private async void LoadEventsForUser(int userId)
        {
            var user = await new UserInterface().GetUser(userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                Title = $"Welcome, {user.FirstName} {user.LastName}!";
            }
        }


        public Command JoinEvent { get; }

        // This is be the line of code I want to execute if I clicked the Join button
        private async void OnJoin(Event selectedEvent)
        {
            if (selectedEvent == null)
                return;

            // Display event details in an alert
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(
                "Event Joined",
                $"You have joined the event:\n\n" +
                $"ID: {selectedEvent.event_id}\n" +
                $"Name: {selectedEvent.event_name}",
                "OK");
        }
    }
}

I want to execute the OnJoin method if I clicked the Join Button, but whenever I add a binding for the button the content will not show. Please Help me. Thank you so much in advance.
I'm expecting to display an alert for now to show that my button is working properly, but unfortunately whenever I add Binding Command to my button the content is not showing.

because JoinEvent is defined on the base of your VM, while the BindingContext of each row is a single Event.  You need to use a relative binding

BindingContext within in the DataTemplate of your ListView will be set to individual item(Event) from the ItemSource(Events).
Since your JoinEvent is in your VM, you need to explicitly specify the reference .
Add x:Name to your parent stacklayout
<StackLayout x:Name="parentStack">

then you can specify your button command as below
     <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Join" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentStack},Path=BindingContext.JoinEvent}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

